# Animate PIL image with TKinter Canvas

Tags: canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Here is my code to put a PIL image on a TKinter canvas. How can I get it to add one pixel at a time instead of the whole image at once?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk
import profile
import re

W = 455
H = 328
img = Image.new("RGB", (W, H), "black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)


for x in range(W):
     for y in range(H):
        color = (x % 255, y % 255, (x % (y+1)) % 255)
        draw.point((x,y), fill=color)
img.save("img.png", "PNG")


root=Tk() 
frame=Frame(root,width=900,height=630) 
frame.grid(row=0,column=0) 
canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=930,height=600) 
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH) 
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
item=canvas.create_image(100,100,anchor=NW,image=imgtk)
mainloop()
```

Comment: You mention using PIL in the title, but you aren't actually using PIL in the code.

Comment: @BryanOakley, he is, Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk are from PIL

Comment: @JohnMoore This seems like a very strange request - can you explain why you want to do that?  I have a feeling there's a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.